# Woocommerce subscription: seperate tax rate, one for the signup fee and second for the recurring payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tax, woocommerce-subscriptions

We have a website that sells subscriptions.
The customer will get a physical product and then will be charged each month for the service.
We use WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin. We set the subscription product so the "Signup fee" will be used to charge for the physical device, and the subscription fee is for the service.

On some US states, the Tax for service and tangibles is different. For us it means different tax rate for the product (one time) and another tax rate for the recurring payment (service).

Since there is only one option to have Tax Class, I could not find a way to make it happen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So...
The answer is to separate the subscription into two products. one as service and one as tangible.
We add the tangible on-the-fly.